# i want to change position random

Tags: for-loop

The onclick event does not repeat

I want the target to move randomly every time I click on it but it only moves once.

thank you in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="target.png" id="tg" onclick="target()">

  <script>
  var a = document.getElementById("tg");
  var x = Math.random()*window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random()*window.innerHeight;

  function target(){a.style.left = x + "px", a.style.top = y + "px";}
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {function target(){a.style.left = x + "px", a.style.top = y + "px";}}
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what language is that? javascript?

Comment: erm im not an expert but i think that you're just declaring the target function in the for loop and no executing it, not sure why you don't get an error that you have redeclared a function with the same name... just try this `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ target();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the target to move randomly, you need to use a random number and you need to set it inside the function so the values would update every time you click and the `target()` function is called.

Also, make sure you are using 'position: absolute;'.

Here is an example on how it can be done:

```html
<body>
    <img src="target.png" id="tg" onclick="target()"   style="position: absolute;">

    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("tg");

        function target() {
            var x = Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - a.clientWidth);
            var y = Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - a.clientHeight);
            a.style.left = x + "px";
            a.style.top = y + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```